# Zend Framework: Routing seems to interfere with rendering of Zend_Navigation menu

Tags: zend-framework

i have setup a route like below in `bootstrap.php`

```
$route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
    'users/:id',
    array(
        'controller' => 'users',
        'action' => 'view'
    )
);
$router->addRoute('viewUser', $route);
```

when i try to goto `/users/1`, and in view script do `echo $page->getHref()`, i get

> Fatal error:
>   Zend_Controller_Router_Exception: id
>   is not specified in
>   D:\ResourceLibrary\Frameworks\ZendFramework\library\Zend\View\Helper\Navigation\HelperAbstract.php
>   on line 522

when i try to goto `/users/view/id/1` it works ok. i am wondering why would rendering menu items from Zend_Navigation crash in something separate like routing?

Answer (score 1):

ok i solved the problem with help from [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1264834/zend-controller-router-exception-xyz-is-not-specified)

basically, i need to add a default value for id

```
$route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
    'users/:id',
    array(
        'controller' => 'users',
        'action' => 'view',
        'id' => '0'
    )
);
$router->addRoute('viewUser', $route);
```

Comment: ops but now i have another problem. i cant go to '/users' cos it will automatically route to '/users/0'