# Zend_Navigation init in Bootstrap

Tags: zend-framework

Zend Framework v1.12

Tryed to init navigation in bootstrap and everything is fine, except appending it to view.
Here is a code snippet:

```
protected function  _initNavigation() {
        $this->bootstrap('view');
        $view = $this->getResource('view');
        include_once 'views/navigation.php';
        $nav = new Zend_Navigation($navigation);
        $view->navigation($nav);
}
```

Error occures because of last line. Stacktrace:

```
Uncaught exception 'Zend_Controller_Router_Exception' with message 'Route archive is not defined' in C:\OpenServer\domains\zend.vortexed\library\Zend\Controller\Router\Rewrite.php:318
Stack trace: #0 C:\OpenServer\domains\zend.vortexed\library\Zend\Navigation\Page\Mvc.php(176): Zend_Controller_Router_Rewrite->getRoute('archive') #1
C:\OpenServer\domains\zend.vortexed\library\Zend\View\Helper\Navigation\HelperAbstract.php(686): Zend_Navigation_Page_Mvc->isActive(false) #2
C:\OpenServer\domains\zend.vortexed\library\Zend\View\Helper\Navigation\Menu.php(740): Zend_View_Helper_Navigation_HelperAbstract->findActive(Object(Zend_Navigation), 0, NULL) #3
C:\OpenServer\domains\zend.vortexed\library\Zend\View\Helper\Navigation\Menu.php(940): Zend_View_Helper_Navigation_Menu->_renderMenu(Object(Zend_Navigation), 'navigation', '', ' ', 0, NULL, false, false, NULL, false, 'active', 'menu-parent', false) #4
C:\OpenServer\domains\zend.vortexed\library\Zend\View\Helper\Navigation\Menu.php(1096): Zend_View_Helper_Navigation_Menu->renderMenu(NULL) 
...
```

Dumping `$nav` shows that it is good.

Also i tryed such variant:

```
protected function  _initNavigation() {
        $this->bootstrap('layout');
        $layout=  $this->getResource('layout');
        $view=  $layout->getView();
        include_once 'views/navigation.php';
        $nav = new Zend_Navigation($navigation);
        $view->navigation($nav);
}
```

...same error

Comment: where is $navigation defined ?

Comment: @DragonWarrior in views/navigation.php

Comment: check this out [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1264834/zend-controller-router-exception-xyz-is-not-specified)

Comment: @DragonWarrior thanks. please arrange it as answer, ill approve it

Comment: glad that helped, i have posted it as a answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different reasons for that error,

Some of them are given in the following answer,

you can find it in here [ROUTER EXCEPTION](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1264834/zend-controller-router-exception-xyz-is-not-specified).

posting link as the answer, which helped The OP to get his answer, for the sake of marking the question as it has served it's purpose..

Answer (score 0):

This is not a view or layout error.
The exception tell you that the route 'archive' is not define.
Start by creating the 'archive' route.

Comment: but i don't need archive route and not use it